# foreign key rails, how to add?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg

To make more simple I do have

```
class User
  has_many :questions, trough: votes
  has_many :questions     #(as the author)
  has_many :votes
end
```

Forgot to add foreign_key when created, now I don't know how to add it to specific (has_many through) association

**schema.rb**

```
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "best",        default: false
  end

  add_index "answers", ["question_id"], name: "index_answers_on_question_id", using: :btree
  add_index "answers", ["user_id"], name: "index_answers_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "file"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.integer  "attachable_id"
    t.string   "attachable_type"
  end

  add_index "attachments", ["attachable_id", "attachable_type"], name: "index_attachments_on_attachable_id_and_attachable_type", using: :btree

  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "questions", ["title"], name: "index_questions_on_title", using: :btree
  add_index "questions", ["user_id"], name: "index_questions_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["name"], name: "index_users_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  add_index "votes", ["user_id", "votable_id"], name: "index_votes_on_user_id_and_votable_id", unique: true, using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "answers", "questions", on_delete: :cascade
  add_foreign_key "questions", "users", on_delete: :cascade
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: you mean user_id in other models

Comment: RaVeN 'code'create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on your console

```
rails g migration AddForeignKeyToVotes user:references question:references
```

This will generate a `xxxx_add_foreign_key_to_votes.rb` file under `db/migrate/` with following contents

```
class AddForeignKeyToVotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :votes, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
    add_reference :votes, :question, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Comment: The thing is I need a foreign key in question. Im a beginner, and may be I do not understand somth. But the purpose of this adding is to make an alias cause I have to has_many :questions, and I would like to add a named foreign key to separate them

Answer (score 0):

Are you really need foreign keys?

Many of Rails developers are comfortable with the way Rails handles relationships in the application rather than the database.

for your case:

```
class User
  has_many :questions, trough: votes
  has_many :questions     #(as the author)
  has_many :votes
```

end

if `votes` table has `question_id` and `user_id` that is enough to define the relation without any foreign keys, unless you have a reason and really need this foreign keys to be defined database level.

Read [THIS SECTION](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#convention-over-configuration-in-active-record) carefully, Rails is using `Convention over Configuration`.

As a small example: how your `User` model know which table to query in and retrieve the data, without any configuration it search for table with same name `users` (convention) and use it, same for foreign keys.

According to your comment you have a model something as Stackoverflow, you have a `User` who can ask a `Question` and can answer a `Question` in this case you may have something like:

```
class User
  has_many :asked_questions, class_name: 'Question'   # user can ask many questions
  has_many :voted_questions, through: :votes, source: 'question'
  has_many :votes # to get all votes this user did
end

class Question
  has_many :votes   # to get all votes for a question
  belongs_to :user
end

class Vote
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Database will be something like:

```
 # Table User
 # Table Question (user_id)
 # Table Vote (user_id, question_id)
```

Let's say you want to get `Questions` user asked they it will be:

```
user = User.first 
user.asked_questions
```

if you want get `Questions` who user votes for:

```
 user.voted_questions
```

Comment: mohamed-ibrahim I need that for addressing separation. may be I am going the wrong way, but I want to address questions as the author and questions as the voter/ These are different associations